# Создание триггера для аудита

Tags: база-данных, postgresql, триггер

Добрый вечер столкнулся с такой проблемой, у меня есть около 40 таблиц в БД, и нужно сделать триггеры аудиты на каждую таблицу, не могли бы вы подсказать как в триггерной функции написать написать возвращение имени таблицы над которой проводились какие то операции точнее меня интересует что писать в этой строке вместо TG_TABLE_NAME

```
INSERT INTO audit.audit SELECT 'Удалил', now(), user, current_query(),TG_TABLE_NAME;
```

вот моя триггерная функция

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_emp_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $emp_audit$
    BEGIN

        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit.audit SELECT 'Удалил', now(), user, current_query(),TG_TABLE_NAME;
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit.audit SELECT 'Обновил', now(), user, current_query(),TG_TABLE_NAME;
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit.audit SELECT 'Добавил', now(), user, current_query(),TG_TABLE_NAME;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        RETURN NULL; 
    END;
$emp_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

а вот сами тригеры

```
CREATE TRIGGER emp_audit1
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON emp1
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_emp_audit();

CREATE TRIGGER emp_audit2
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON emp2
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_emp_audit();
```

и таблица в которую заносятся изменения

```
CREATE TABLE audit.audit 
(
 ID                 SERIAL          NOT NULL        PRIMARY KEY,
 Operation          VARCHAR         NOT NULL,
 DateTime           TimeStamp       NOT NULL,
 IDUser             TEXT            NOT NULL,
 QUERY              TEXT            NOT NULL,
 NameTable          TEXT            NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зачем что-то писать вместо `TG_TABLE_NAME`, когда именно эта переменная вам и нужна? Это такая же специальная [автоматически созданная](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-trigger.html) в контексте вызова триггера `plpgsql` переменная, как и уже используемая у вас `TG_OP`.

Необходимо лишь поправить `insert` запросы в вашей функции для соответствия вашей же таблице аудита:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_emp_audit() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $emp_audit$
    BEGIN

        IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit.audit (operation, datetime, iduser, query, nametable) SELECT 'Удалил', now(), user, current_query(),TG_TABLE_NAME;
            RETURN OLD;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit.audit (operation, datetime, iduser, query, nametable) SELECT 'Обновил', now(), user, current_query(),TG_TABLE_NAME;
            RETURN NEW;
        ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
            INSERT INTO audit.audit (operation, datetime, iduser, query, nametable) SELECT 'Добавил', now(), user, current_query(),TG_TABLE_NAME;
            RETURN NEW;
        END IF;
        raise exception 'impossible TG_OP=%', TG_OP;
    END;
$emp_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Плюс я заменил `return NULL` на создание исключения. `TG_OP` соответствует операциям указанным в `CREATE TRIGGER`, а вот при `return NULL` никаких ошибок сгенерировано не будет, но и сама выполняемая запросом операция будет отменена. Я не считаю полезным такое тихое скрытое взаимодействие. Лучше заметным образом получить исключение в ситуации нарушения логики процедуры.